# I want to show and hide a element (ActivityIndicator)

Tags: javascript, react-native

What I'm trying to do is when I click the button it disappears, and when it's already loaded in another component it shows again the button.

JSX code:

```
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
     {......}
    {/button besides loading/}
                    <LinearGradient
                        colors={['#D97B29', '#F2B47E']}
                        style={styles.signIn}
                    >
                        <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                            color:'#fff'
                        }]}>Entrar</Text>
                        {/loading besides button /}
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#D97B29" />
                    </LinearGradient>
                      {...}
```

How can I handle it whit the useState?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to hide/show the indicator when the button is pressed, you need

```
const [ showLoader, setShowLoader ] = useState(false);
```

Your button on press should show something like

```
<Button onPress={() => setShowLoader(!showLoader)} text="Some text" />
```

and your code should look like

````
              {showLoader && (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#D97B29" />             
              )}
              {!showLoader && <LinearGradient
                        colors={['#D97B29', '#F2B47E']}
                        style={styles.signIn}
                    >
                        <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                            color:'#fff'
                        }]}>Entrar</Text>
                    </LinearGradient> }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
{state && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#D97B29" />}
```

if `state` is `true` it will show the component